# ASP.NET: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a index table to manage database on ASP.NET MVC. When I created new a product it ran out this error. What does that mean and how to fix it ?

`Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'Production.Product' with unique index 'AK_Product_rowguid'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a field in your insert. You should add something like this in your `insert` statement:

```
insert
into product
( ... -- other column names
, your_column_name
)
values
( ... -- other values
, newid()
)
```

Comment: The problem in ASP.NET but it's OK with your answer. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TrungPham: I think you don't understand what is going on. The error message is a SQL Server error message, not an ASP.NET error message.

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong, it happened in SQL Server. Now I fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` is `uniqueidentifier` in `sql` or `system.Guid` in ASP. it has not been initialized yet, so i presume u are transmitting this value from ASP. Try adding a new parameter to your query with `system.guid.newguid()`, or `system.guid.newguid.tostring` if your query uses parameters.

If you are creating t-sql script to be exectued (ex: `"insert into production.product values('"+TextBox1.Text+"', newid())"` or `"insert into production.product values('"+TextBox1.Text+"', '"+system.guid.newguid.tostring()+"')"`.

You can define for the uniqueidentifier column of product table a default value `newid()`.

Comment: @TrungPham: and what is your question?

Comment: I don't understand it either. Do you get some error message?

Comment: I added `System.Guid.NewGuid()` in `Action` and an error is gone. Sorry for my inconvenience.

Comment: @Andras: +1 for the helping attitude!

Comment: @Patrick: Now I understand the problem I had, please +1 for me!